User Rename events via the admin sdk are not showing in Workspace Admin Console Investigation Tool Logs
Is anyone else having this issue?
We have a 3rd party application that we use for user provisioning and deprovisioning.
When the application deletes a user it first renames the user.
For example if it was deleting a user named joe.smith@domain.com the actions would be:

User Rename joe.smith@domain.com to 13413534341@domain.com
User Deletion 13413534341@domain.com

However, only the User Deletion event is appearing in the Admin Log.
This is a problem because if we want to recover the account we don't know what the orginal account was renamed to before the delete occurred.
Regardless of that process, the question is, Why are the User Rename events not appearing in the logs.
explained in the details section

Just to be clear. The problem only occurs when a User Rename and a User Deletion happen within quick succession.
